# Email-SMS gateway in China (China Mobile)

Tags: email, sms, sms-gateway

I was developing a simple SMS application using the Email-SMS Gateways that various Phone companies provide.

So for instance you can send a SMS message by appending a carrier specific email suffix to the mobile number. **i.e** for AT&T:
For the phone number `111-222-3333`, it's corresponding Email is `1112223333@txt.att.net`

The specific Mobile provider that I am trying to send/receive from is China Mobile ([中国移动通信集团公司](http://10086.cn/)). I have found very extensive lists for virtually all other carriers (Both US and International), but can't seem to find one for this Chinese Carrier.

So my question is:

1. Is there a public Email-SMS gateway (Such that you could fire an SMS message from a standard email client or server-side scripting langauge like PHP)
2. If not, then is there any way to get around it, via other services (legally of course).

Thanks

Comment: Here's a list of many other Carriers and their email-sms gateway http://www.emailtextmessages.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found this. This seems useful. I'm gonna test it soon for my company.

http://www.now.cn/mobile/  (In Chinese.  The English version doesn't seem to have the information about SMS sending)

```
Plan 1: 1000  SMS for 99 RMB.
Plan 2: 5000  SMS for 449 RMB.
Plan 3: 20000 SMS for 1699 RMB.
```

Answer (score 1):

It **might** be blocked in China (best way to see this is to check if other Chinese carriers offer this).

If no public e-mail address pattern is found for China Mobile, try another service that already provides this for CM and check if they have an API.

Comment: Considering that China notoriously blocks content that allows Chinese citizens to easily communicate with foreigners, and that I can't find <b>any</b> other public gateways in China I think you are correct.